# EmberJS requiredKeys for action

Tags: javascript, events, ember.js, keypress

How can I define an action (on click) which is only call when a specific modifier key is pressed?

[allowedKeys](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.2.0/templates/actions/#toc_allowing-modifier-keys) also executes the action when no modifier keys are pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach will be just do

```
<div onclick={{action 'itemClick'}}> my item </div>
```

and in your controller/parent component

```
actions: {
  itemClick(e){
    if (e.altKey) {
       // alt key 
    } else if (e.ctrlKey) {
       // ctrl key 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to trigger on click, sorry for not specifying it. I update the question.

Comment: you want to catch it on button ?